# privately or publicly inherit from boost::non_copyable?

Tags: c++, inheritance, boost

Which practice would you recommend, and why?

```
class Foo : public boost::noncopyable {};
```

vs.

```
class Foo : private boost::noncopyable {};
```

I can't imagine needing to use an instance of Foo as a boost::noncopyable, so I'm leaning toward private inheritance in this case.

Comment: I always do: `class Foo: boost::noncopyable` :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`boost::noncopyable` does not declare a `virtual` destructor, i.e. is not designed to be the base of public inheritance chain. Always inherit from it **privately**.

Answer (score 3):

I think that from higher point of view it should be `public` inheritance. The reasons to make it `private` are purely technical.

Why? Because whether a type is copyable or not (and this is shown by inheriting from `boost::noncopyable`) is part of *public* interface. For example if the inheritance would be `public` you would be able to check (using "meta programming") whether type derives from `boost::noncopyable` and then reason about whether it is copyable or not.

Nikolai N Fetissov [in his answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5654386/422489) points out that `boost::noncopyable` doesn't have `virtual` destructor and so should not be used as `public` base class. While that it a valid argument in general I think it is so unlikely that anyone ever would try to use (and `delete` in particular) an object by a pointer to `boost::noncopyable` that it makes the argument (in this particular case) purely academic.

Come on! If someone is so inclined to misuse code that he uses `delete` on a pointer to `boost::noncopyable` then there is no way to be safe. Sure you can make it a bit harder but a programmer so determined will find some other way to misuse code anyway.

Also it seems that in C++11 `boost::noncopyable` could solve that issue by declaring `default` `protected` destructor:

```
protected:
    ~noncopyable() = default;
```

This way there should be no additional cost of declaring destructor (since we made it `default`) while we are protected from `delete` on a pointer to `boost::noncopyable`.

On the other hand however it also seems unlikely that anyone will be willing to check whether a type is copyable by checking inheritance from `boost::noncopyable`. Mostly because it doesn't provide complete answer. Just because a type doesn't derive from `boost::noncopyable` it doesn't mean that it is copyable.

Note also that [Boost.Noncopyable docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/core/doc/html/core/noncopyable.html#core.noncopyable.header_boost_core_noncopyable_hp) suggest use of `private` inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Boost document](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/core/doc/html/core/noncopyable.html)

> It is intended to be used as a private base.